# do EJBs get injected on a servlet everytime a request is done on the servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, ejb

I am trying to copy the MVC design pattern. And this is what I do, I have a servlet which handles all the requests. In it, are the injected ejbs. So in this controller/servlet is declared 7 to 15 ejbs with the @EJB annotations.

I just want to ask if for example, 1 user calls the maincontroller/servlet. do the ejbs get injected only on that call or everytime a user calls the servlet do they get injected everytime? or the ejbs are injected the first time the servlet is created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Injection is done when creating the object and since Servlet Container  usually (but not mandatory - in case of single thread model) creates a single instance of a servlet and then serves the request in separate thread, the EJB in your case should be created once in case you are not using SingleThreadModel.

Comment: This is not true. SingleThreadModel only means that the servlet can serve only one thread at a time. The servlet container will always create an instance of a servlet ONLY ONCE ( singlethreadmodel or not ).

Comment: @Kal Check the Servlet Specification - SRV.2.2.1 it says --- "The use of the SingleThreadModel interface guarantees that only one thread at a
time will execute in a given servlet instance’s service method. It is important to
note that this guarantee only applies to each servlet instance, since the container
may choose to pool such objects" which essentially means that there can be multiple instances

Answer (score 2):

Resources are injected at the time of object creation ( since you cannot inject into static fields, but just member variables ).

In the case of a servlet, the servlet class is loaded by the servlet container and then an instance is created. At this time, the `@EJB or @Resource` is injected. The container then calls the init() method

Comment: thanks for the clarification and just to make sure I got it right, after the servlet is created (and so it ejbs) then, if 10 users would access the servlet, during that process the creation or injection of an ejb won't happen anymore because it is already done on the first place it was created

Comment: Yes.Unless they are stateful session beans. In which case, you will have as many as there are sessions.